# Sending emails in PHP and using Google Apps mail as SMTP is too slow

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, gmail, google-apps

Currently I've been using PHP and the Zend Framework to send emails with SMTP and GMail's SMTP servers. That's because I have a Google Apps domain setup to handle all my emails so it looks like my emails are coming from mailer@mycompany.com.

Now when a user registers or does something which requires my web server to send an email to them this can take 5 seconds or so on the PHP side to initiate the SMTP connection and send the email to them. The process would be something like this:

1. User completes registration form
2. User submits form
3. PHP script saves information to database and sends them an email (5-10 seconds)
4. User redirected to another page

Now when they've just submitted the form I can't have a massive delay from my web server while the user sits there for 10 seconds looking like it's loading. Basically the send email process is single threaded so the server can't do anything else until it's completed sending the email which is anywhere between 5-10 seconds, sometimes 20 seconds if there's an error with the email address so this is far too long.

How to people normally get around issues like this?

Originally I tried a few things:

1. Using another library like SwiftMailer. Still same problem. I think it's the SMTP/TLS handshake which takes extra time.
2. Storing the email data in a database and then using fsockopen to initiate an asynchronous request to another page which would then get the email data from the database and send the email. Meanwhile my PHP script could continue synchronously and the user would get redirected to the next page immediately after the form submission. Problem was there was no way to confirm whether the email was sent, or if it failed. I could set a flag on the database table I suppose but I wanted to provide instant feedback to the user that their email had been sent. That meant on the next page, firing off an Ajax request after 10 seconds to another page which would check the flag on the database table to see if it was sent or not, then show the response on the page to the user. This wouldn't work if they entered the email wrong and it couldn't send the email, as the response from GMail would sometimes take 20 seconds for an error case, then the database flag wouldn't be set.
3. Another option I came up with was to put the email data in the $_SESSION array, so after submitting the page and the user is on the redirected page it would send an ajax request off to another page which would get the session data and send the email, then send a response back to the page the user was on and tell them the email was sent. This works pretty well, but I feel it's probably not the best way.

So I'm wondering what's the best practice way to do it? Is GMail too slow for this kind of thing as it has to do the TLS handshake? Should I just queue up all the emails into the database and run a CRON job every few minutes to send them off, then remove them from the database once sent? Problem with that is there's no instant feedback given to the user that their email was sent correctly. Or do I not need to bother with that anyway? They either get the email or not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using your host's email smtp server and setting the from address manually? This has typically worked for me. If that is not an option, my first reaction would be option 3 - this is similar to what Google mail does when you select the option for delayed sending in their web ui.

Comment: How do you mean using my host's email SMTP server? I'm using my own VPS, so I'd have to set all that up myself right?

Comment: @Dagon, do you have any guides for setting this up on Linux? Last time I looked at it, I got lost. Is this right... my web server will send the email (maybe using PHP's send() method) to be processed by my mail server on the same web server machine. That mail server then sends the email to the user using Google Apps SMTP or does it use some other email address that I have to set up?

Comment: what os is the server running?

Comment: @Dagon it's running Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Typically, if sendmail is configured correctly, then you can invoke the mail() method in PHP, and one of the parameters you can pass is the "From" address. If you're worried about your email being routed to spam you can explore deploying SPF records (they're fairly simple and quite quick). If you haven't used the mail method before, a quick reference is available at: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp. I've also got a simple mailer object that I use up at https://github.com/kaiesh/PHPLightweightFramework/blob/master/PHP-objects/kkMailMessage.php (works, but is in progress tho)

Comment: @zuallaz, sorry didn't clarify your first question - if you use the PHP mail function without specifiying an alternate SMTP provider, then your server negotiaties directly with the recipients MX. So Google is left out of it - but if the FROM address is set correctly, then the user sees this as coming from your mailbox. I haven't ever really had any issues with spam trapping, because the message is coming from the server where the domain is hosted - but you can be extra cautious and use SPF records to protect against aggressive spam filters.

Comment: This sounds like it would work well. I think I may have tried this method initially but got lost trying to configure the sendmail server on linux? Are you saying I don't even need to configure sendmail on my server, PHP just communicates with the recipients MX server directly?

Comment: @zuallauz in my experience (and I think it depends on your linux distro) sendmail has been configured right out of the box to support sending mail to other MX servers. It's when you want to configure it to receive mail that you need to jump through some hoops. In ubuntu, you can simply run "apt-get install sendmail" and it should autoconfigure for sending. Can you run this PHP script on your server to test it? <? mail(<YOUR EMAIL HERE>, "Test subject", "Test body", "From: no-reply@<YOUR DOMAIN>.com\r\n"); ?> It may take a few seconds to receive.

Answer (score 1):

What about writing an apps script and using it as a webapp just to handle the e-mail.  You can use HTTP Get with params to have apps script send the e-mail using the base mail service. MailApp.sendEmail()

I'm  a self taught apps script guy so I'm just speculating here, but in theory it should work.  I think it would look something like this.

You should be able to pass the keys at the end of e.parameter through the webApp url.

```
function doGet(e){
var userEmail = e.parameter.email;

var body = 'message here';//could even pass params for the body also.

MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, 'Subject', 'body', {noReply: true});
}
```

All our stuff is built on apps script and I have dozens of email notifications going out, and in apps script its instant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem, What I actually do is that I just queue them in database and I have a cronjob that runs every minute to send emails queued in database.

by the way, many mid-sized sites do this, and tell you you should receive an email within (5 minutes) or shortly ........etc

The benefits of saving in db is that you can add an extra column to indicate if it's sent or not and to retry if it's not sent in the next cronjob.

---

**Update for locking the Cronjob:**

Please notice that this is a sequential logic only and notice that step 1,2, and 4 are about Cron #1

```
1-Cron #1 runs at 12:05, reads the locking table and finds it empty so it creates a db record in a pre-created table "locking" with 1 field "cronlock": holding the value 12345678910, which is the current time stamp.

2-Cron #1 at 12:06 (Still sending emails, but it completed 6 emails so far) so it updates the record of locking again with the current time-stamp to extend the locking period.

3-Cron #2 runs at 12:07, reads the locking table and find a value, compares this value with the current timestamp if the difference is less than 120 seconds, then it terminates itself.

4-Cron #1 finishes sending some emails at 12:08, it deletes the locking record and quits.**

5-Cron #3 runs at 12:09 and finds no locking record so it creates a new one and starts sending.... and so on.
```

Comment: Lets say I encounter a busy period of traffic to my site and have 50+ emails queued up in the database to send out. It takes about 5-10 seconds to send each email. Conceivably the next cronjob may run again and start sending the same list of emails as the other cronjob hasn't finished yet. Then customers would get 2 emails which would be pretty bad. How would you get around that concurrency issue? Maybe set a flag on the row in the table that it's attempting to send that one? So if the next cronjob comes around it will ignore that row and continue to another one?

Comment: Add a lock field with timestamp for locking and update it if it was sent or release the lock if it wasn't

Comment: Yeah cool that should work, thanks. Do you keep the sent emails in the database indefinitely? Or do you clear them out at some point? I was thinking I could clear them out once sent, as the address I'm sending the mail from will still have a copy if I log into Google Apps and have a look if I really need to.

Comment: Look you can lock in an easier way, lock the cron itself. i.e. when a new cron starts it checks if the last cron is still locking the emails or not, if so then it quits, if not then it proceeds with sending and make the locking based on timestamp, such that if for any reason the cron script was terminated in the middle before unlocking the record or files or field that you'll specify; it remains locked for at most, let's say 3 minutes, and make sure you update this locking every X-number of emails such that you make sure the lock doesn't timeout while you're still sending.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm using same components to send emails. But I'm sending emails in background using `Zend_Queue` in this case visitors don't have to wait. This is how I accomplish this task (`Zend_Queue` is initialized in `Bootstap.php`) :

**1.Creating job**

```
class My_Job_SendEmail extends My_Job
{
    /**
     * Message subject:
     * 
     * @var string|null 
     */
    protected $_subject = null;

    /**
     * Message body:
     * @var string|null 
     */
    protected $_message = null;

    /**
     * Message To:
     * @var string|null 
     */
    protected $_to = null;

    public function __construct(Zend_Queue $queue, array $options = null)
    {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }

        parent::__construct($queue);
    }

    public function job()
    {
        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->addTo($this->_to);
        $mail->setSubject($this->_subject);
        $mail->setBody($this->_message);
        return $mail->send();
    }
}
```

**2.Source of [My_Job](https://gist.github.com/2899315)**

**3.Adding job to the queue (probably somewhere inside your service)**

```
$backgroundJob = new My_Job_SendEmail(Zend_Registry::get('queue'), array(
    'to'      => $to,
    'bcc'     => $bcc,
    'subject' => $subject,
    'message' => $message,
));

$backgroundJob->execute();
```

**4.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954616/how-do-i-access-my-models-using-a-daemon-in-zend-framework/10958277#10958277) answer, for an example of background script.**

**5.Add background script to the cronjob**

`*/1 * * * * php /path/to/project/background/emailQueue.php`